# How to play more than 1 .wav sounds in C++ at the same time using PlaySound() or any basic function/method?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, audio, wav

I am trying to make a game where I need to play many sounds simultaneously I know v.basic or rather just know about the func. `PlaySound()` to run `.wav` sounds.

The problem is that with `SND_ASYNC` I cannot play multiple sound at once but the sound which plays first skips in the middle and plays the next sound.

Is there any way (simple and easy to understand) so that I can play multiple sounds at once?

Comment: Have you tried googling for "playsound multiple sounds"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Playsound is not meant for mixing sounds. Essentially, it's an older technology that can easily be outdone by more recent ones.

You can use [DirectX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb318770%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for sound development in games (a popular choice).

I personally use [FMod](http://www.fmod.org/download/) since it's really easy to use. [Here is a tutorial to get you started](http://forum.devmaster.net/t/introduction-to-c-with-game-development-part-20-sound/2862).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the latest version of fmod (fmod Studio) that give you posibilities to create diferen channels and play various sounds on each channel and aply effects for each one.