# Thread Background music in MFC single Document

Tags: c++, mfc, playsound

i`m trying to implement a background music loop and do other sounds that wont cut it when I use the "PlaySound" function again.

```
    void CcpPongView::playBGsound(int num)
{
    //added in the linker to additional name : winmm.lib
    if(num)
        PlaySound(L"sound.wav", NULL, SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);
}

void CcpPongView::initGame()
{
    std::thread test (playBGsound, 1);
    test.join();
}
```

this is the second place I use Playsound

```
    void Ball::playSound()
{
    switch (rand()%2) {
    case 0:PlaySound(sounds[0], NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        break;
    case 1:PlaySound(sounds[1], NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        break;
}
```

im not sure where I need to place the thread or how to make a thread in mfc Single Document..
(the "num" was to test)

[image]

[image]
if there is another way to do it i`m all ears
thanks for the help every one :)

Answer (score 3):

Your creation of the `std::thread` needs to be more like this instead:

```
std::thread test (&CcpPongView::playBGsound, this, 1);
```

Note that calling `join()` on the thread immediately after creating it is a waste of a thread. You may as well just call `playBGSound()` directly.  If you want to create a thread and let it keep running after the `std::thread` is destroyed, call `detach()` instead of `join()`. Otherwise, don't destroy the `std::thread` until after the thread has stopped running (ie, store it in a member of your `CcpPongView` class), in which case you can then use `join()`.

And, [you can't play multiple sounds simultaneously with `PlaySound()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144635/) using the `SND_ASYNC` flag.